# setAttribute() is setting the text of function as href value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The title probably didn't make any sense so here's what's happening. I'm trying to run an `onclick()` function that will swap stylesheets for a visual change. The way I'm doing it is to `replace()` part of the `href`value. Specifically, I'm changing the word **white** to **black** in order to change the value of the `href` from `styles-black.css` to styles-black.css.

I'm doing this with no problem in jQuery:

```
$(".onoffswitch").click(function(){
  if($('.onoffswitch-checkbox').is(':checked') == false) {            
    $("#pagestyle").attr('href', function(i, blackCSS) {
        return blackCSS.replace('white', 'black');                
    });            
  }
```

});

I'm no expert so this might be very inefficient but I'm still trying to learn. 
Now, when I try to replicate this using vanilla JS i get some weird results. First, here's my code:

```
document.getElementById("pagestyle").setAttribute("href", (function(i,blackCss) {
        return blackCSS.replace("white", "black");
    }))
```

After I run it, I follow it up with `document.getElementById('pagestyle').getAttribute('href');`to check the value of the `href` to see whether or not the function worked and.....this is what I'm getting:

```
"function (i,blackCss) {
        return blackCSS.replace("white", "black");
    }"
```

Here's the element:

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="function (i,blackCss) {&#10;            return blackCSS.replace(&quot;white&quot;, &quot;black&quot;);&#10;        }">
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. The weird thing is that if I weren't checking myself, I'd think it worked! The styles change. If I inspect the elements using Chrome/IE tools, I can see that the styles for styles-black.css are being applied! But why the hell is it showing the function in the element's attribute? That can't be right can it? Of course, I'm open to anyone who wants to show me how it's done.

**Edit**
Here's the initial state of the element:

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='css/styles-white.css'>
```

Comment: You... aren't calling the function. `setAttribute("href", (function(i,blackCss) { blah blah blah; })() );` <- missing () there.

Comment: You can't just replace complex jQuery methods with basic JavaScript ones and expect it to just work. You probably want `pagestyle.href = pagestyle.href.replace("white","black");` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected, because attribute values can only be strings, so your function is converted to a string.

In vanilla-js you do it like this:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("pagestyle"),
    initial = el.getAttribute("href");
el.href = initial.replace("white", "black");
```

```html
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='css/styles-white.css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the function with adding `()` at the end

```
document.getElementById("pagestyle").setAttribute("href", (function(blackCss) {
        return blackCSS.replace("white", "black");
    })(document.getElementById("pagestyle").href)) ;
```

Comment: blackCSS would be undefined

Comment: blackCss suppose to be the value of href for the `pagestyle`

Comment: Yes, this was undefined, you point to this and I fix it, thanks